# Dataset in .h5 file with type "|V376">

Tags: fft, h5py

I am trying to get MRI image data from a .h5 file, but the dataset in which I suppose is the tensor needed to print the image is stored in a (10440,) type "|V376"> dataset. What I need is a squared matrix that I can transform with fft2 and visualize the k-space. Is there a way to know where I need to look for the data? I downloaded the file from here: http://mridata.org/list?project=Stanford%202D%20FSE. I tried to download different files but they all have this strange type...

I printed the 'data' item contained in the singular group that is in the .h5 file, and what I get is an array of lists and every list has an array of floats at the end. I extracted these arrays at the end but they do not have a square shape, so they cannot be used to form an image.

Comment: Knowing `data.shape`, and `data.dtype` would help.  You may have to repeat that for one or more elements of `data`, e.g `data[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of HDF5 is a container, not a fixed format. So, as noted above, before you can't read the datasets until you understand the schema. I dug thru the documentation at the mridata.org website. It's a complicated schema! Basically, the MRI data is in a dataset named `['dataset']['data']`. This dataset is a compound dataset (e.g., stores a mix of datatypes as 'fields/columns'). To complicate matters, some of the fields are also compound datasets. Fortunately, the image data *I think* you want is in a simple field (also named `'data'`). This field contains object data (which is how np.arrays are stored when saved with this data structure).

To test my theory, I download the 1st file at the referenced site. (filename: `efac30a2-8b30-48e8-9a7c-aad2a05a46df.h5`. Code below interogates the file and prints the shape and dtype of the `['dataset']['data']` dataset. It has `shape= (5824,)`, so there are 5824 "rows" of image data. It then loops over the 1st 5 rows of that dataset. First, the image shape is extracted from the `'head'` field as `channels` and `samples`. Next, the image array is extracted from the `'data'` field. (I'm 99.9% sure this is the image data you want.) The dtype is set to `np.complex64` and the array is
reshaped to `(channels,samples)`. As expected, the resulting arrays are all `shape=((16, 352))` and `dtype=complex64`. Note `img_data_arr`  is the what I think you want.

Code below:

```
with h5py.File('efac30a2-8b30-48e8-9a7c-aad2a05a46df.h5','r') as h5f:
    for name, h5_obj in h5f['dataset'].items():
        if isinstance(h5_obj, h5py.Dataset):
            print(f'For dataset: {name}; Shape: {h5_obj.shape}')
            print(h5_obj.dtype)
            
    head = h5f['dataset']['data']['head']
    data = h5f['dataset']['data']['data']
    print('\nFor data field in data dataset:'\
          f'\nShape: {data.shape}, Dtype: {data.dtype}') 
    for i in range(5):
        channels = head[i]['active_channels']
        samples = head[i]['number_of_samples']
        print(f"i={i}, #channels={channels}, #samples={samples}") 
        img_data_arr = data[i][()].view(np.complex64).reshape((channels,samples))
        print(i, img_data_arr.shape, img_data_arr.dtype)
```

Note: the mridata.org website also the Python code to build a complete set of tools to read and work with this data. Note: My method follows `class Dataset` definition in the hdf5.py file of the ISMRMRD code that extracts the data.